# Iterating an Array List to calculate the percentage of population growth

Tags: java, loops, csv, arraylist

I want to create a method calculate the percent change of population growth from the years 1994-2013, and prints out each percentage change. I have the data all stored in, but I am not sure how to iterate the ArrayList to accomplish this

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
public class USCrimeClass 
{

public int year;
public int population;
public int violentCrime;
public double violentCrimeRate;
public int manslaughter;
public double manslaughterRate;
public int rape;
public double rapeRate;
public int robbery;
public double robberyRate;
public int assault;
public double assaultRate;
public int propertyCrime;
public double propertyCrimeRate;
public int burglary;
public double burglaryRate;
public int larcenyTheft;
public double larcenyTheftRate;
public int vehicleTheft;
public double vehicleTheftRate;

public USCrimeClass(String line)
{
    String[]split=line.split(",");
    year=Integer.parseInt(split[0]);
    population=Integer.parseInt(split[1]);
    violentCrime=Integer.parseInt(split[2]);
    violentCrimeRate=Double.parseDouble(split[3]);
    manslaughter=Integer.parseInt(split[4]);
    manslaughterRate=Double.parseDouble(split[5]);
    rape=Integer.parseInt(split[6]);
    rapeRate=Double.parseDouble(split[7]);
    robbery=Integer.parseInt(split[8]);
    robberyRate=Double.parseDouble(split[9]);
    assault=Integer.parseInt(split[10]);
    assaultRate=Double.parseDouble(split[11]);
    propertyCrime=Integer.parseInt(split[12]);
    propertyCrimeRate=Double.parseDouble(split[13]);
    burglary=Integer.parseInt(split[14]);
    burglaryRate=Double.parseDouble(split[15]);
    larcenyTheft=Integer.parseInt(split[16]);
    larcenyTheftRate=Double.parseDouble(split[17]);
    vehicleTheft=Integer.parseInt(split[18]);
    vehicleTheftRate=Double.parseDouble(split[19]);
}



Scanner read = null;
{
try
{
    read=new Scanner(new File("C:\\Crime.csv"));
}
catch(FileNotFoundException e)
{
    System.out.println("The file can't be opened");
    System.exit(0);
}
List<USCrimeClass> crimeClasses = new ArrayList<>();
read.nextLine();
while(read.hasNextLine())
{
    crimeClasses.add(new USCrimeClass(read.nextLine()));
}

read.close();



}



}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some of the items I'm going to point out are more code review items that aren't specifically related to the business logic of what you're trying to do, however, in the long run your code will be more readable and maintainable.

First, it's a good idea to separate your data model from your controller logic. The controller handles the business logic whereas the data model stores the data and provides methods to access and change the data. You should also name the class appropriately - using the name `USCrimeClass` could be improved because it's obvious that this is a class, you don't have to use the word "class" in the name. You should also create getter and setter methods for your class member variables rather than allowing direct access. In the code sample below I have created a single getter and setter pair for the `population` field as an example.

```
public class USCrimeData {

    private int year;
    private int population;
    private int violentCrime;
    private double violentCrimeRate;
    private int manslaughter;
    private double manslaughterRate;
    private int rape;
    private double rapeRate;
    private int robbery;
    private double robberyRate;
    private int assault;
    private double assaultRate;
    private int propertyCrime;
    private double propertyCrimeRate;
    private int burglary;
    private double burglaryRate;
    private int larcenyTheft;
    private double larcenyTheftRate;
    private int vehicleTheft;
    private double vehicleTheftRate;

    public USCrimeData(String line) {
        String[] split = line.split(",");
        year = Integer.parseInt(split[0]);
        population = Integer.parseInt(split[1]);
        violentCrime = Integer.parseInt(split[2]);
        violentCrimeRate = Double.parseDouble(split[3]);
        manslaughter = Integer.parseInt(split[4]);
        manslaughterRate = Double.parseDouble(split[5]);
        rape = Integer.parseInt(split[6]);
        rapeRate = Double.parseDouble(split[7]);
        robbery = Integer.parseInt(split[8]);
        robberyRate = Double.parseDouble(split[9]);
        assault = Integer.parseInt(split[10]);
        assaultRate = Double.parseDouble(split[11]);
        propertyCrime = Integer.parseInt(split[12]);
        propertyCrimeRate = Double.parseDouble(split[13]);
        burglary = Integer.parseInt(split[14]);
        burglaryRate = Double.parseDouble(split[15]);
        larcenyTheft = Integer.parseInt(split[16]);
        larcenyTheftRate = Double.parseDouble(split[17]);
        vehicleTheft = Integer.parseInt(split[18]);
        vehicleTheftRate = Double.parseDouble(split[19]);
    }

    public int getPopulation() {
        return population;
    }

    public void setPopulation(int population) {
        this.population = population;
    }
}
```

Next let's talk about the controller. This is where the business logic will reside. This is where you will use your data model to arrive at the results you desire. Since you want to determine the percent population change you would use the list of crime data to get the population from the year 1994 (I assume this is the first entry in the list - index 0) and then get the last entry in the list (I assume the final entry is 2013) then calculate the value you want. If these assumptions are not correct or if you want to calculate growth for different years you would want to implement a `getYear()` method in your data model and then loop through your list of data until you find the object with the year you want.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Controller {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner read = null;

        try {
            // Replace the "..." below with actual path to your data file.
            read = new Scanner(new File("..."));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("The file can't be opened");
            System.exit(0);
        }
        List<USCrimeData> crimeClasses = new ArrayList<>();

        while (read.hasNextLine()) {
            crimeClasses.add(new USCrimeData(read.nextLine()));
        }

        read.close();

        int initialPopulation = crimeClasses.get(0).getPopulation();
        System.out.println("initialPopulation: "+initialPopulation);
        int latestPopulation = crimeClasses.get(crimeClasses.size()-1).getPopulation();
        System.out.println("latestPopulation: "+latestPopulation);
        double percentGrowth = (double)(latestPopulation - initialPopulation) / initialPopulation * 100;

        System.out.println("percentGrowth: "+percentGrowth);
    }

}
```

Comment: I see what you mean. Thank you for the clarification.

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate list like :

```
Iterator<USCrimeClass> iterator = crimeClasses.iterator();
while(iterator.hasNext()) {
  USCrimeClass currentCrime = iterator.next();
  // use currentCrime object to calcuate percent increase/decrease.
}
```

Comment: So after I initialize the currentCrime object, do I iterate to the next item on the list, and then do the calculations? It's been a while since I've used Array Lists